# Oracle WebLogic Server 12c with Java EE 7 on 32-bit Windows: Which SDK?

Tags: java, weblogic, 32-bit

I have to maintain a legacy web application and need to setup an test environment on a 32-bit Windows Notebook with a remote database. I have installed **oepe-12.1.2.4-luna-distro-win32.zip** from Orace and now want to setup the Oracle WebLogic Server (WLS) 12c (12.1.2) as an application server.

Maybe you can help me to answer following questions:

1. What Java 7 development kit do I need for WLS (Java EE or Java SE JDK) ?
2. Where do I get a 32-bit version for the Intel Core i5?
3. Is it possible to install WLS and JDK without extended (administrative) privileges?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think you need a 32-bit JDK?

Comment: It is a Windows 7 Enterprise OS with 32-bit only.

Comment: That's not an appropriate OS to run anything "enterprise" in the 21st century. The 4GB memory limit is s serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.
You need only Java SE JDK, Java EE implementation is provided by WLS.

2.
you can download only 12.1.3 from oracle.com. To get a different version you must create an SR at support.oracle.com

3.
I remember installing without admin privileges, however I am not 100% sure.